# What kind of people falls on this category of "who master a hard lot with their heads held high"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I didn't get this because of **my poor comprehension in English**. **Please help me.**

“Austrian public-opinion pollsters recently reported that those held in highest esteem by most of the people interviewed are neither the great artists nor the great scientists, neither the great statesmen nor the great sports figures, but those who master **a hard lot with their heads held high.**”

Comment: Please provide a source for your quote and explain what you have done already.  Describe the *results* of using a dictionary, or searching the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone's **[lot in life](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/someone-s-lot-in-life#:%7E:text=DEFINITIONS1-,1,Synonyms%20and%20related%20words)** is their general situation or luck. "A hard lot" is a difficult or unfortunate situation that is out of the person's control. You can see it cited with other similar phrases in [this link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/difficulty).

To do something with your **[head held high](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+your+head+held+high)** is to do it with self-confidence and pride, or without showing negativity or shame.

So altogether, the sentence means that the people who were interviewed by the pollsters reported that the people they most respect are the ones who overcome difficult situations with self-confidence.